# How to prove that $\int (1-z)^{u} z^{v} dz$ is equal to $\frac{z^{v+1}}{v+1}_2F_1(-u, v+1; v+2; z)$?

Tags: integration, integral-transforms, integral-operators

How to prove that

$$\int (1-z)^{u} z^{v} dz = \frac{z^{v+1}}{v+1} \, _2F_1(-u, v+1; v+2; z)?$$

Comment: this is Euler's integral, it is evaluated by using the binomial expansion of $(1-z)^u$; see for example theorem 1 in https://homepage.tudelft.nl/11r49/documents/wi4006/hyper.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generalized binomial coefficients are
$$
\binom{u}{n} := \frac{(-1)^n(-u)_n}{n!} ,
$$
here we used the notation $(-u)_n$ for the rising factorial: $(-u)_n := \prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(-u+k)$.

Taylor's expansion of $(1-z)^u$ around $z=0$ is
$$
(1-z)^u = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{u}{v}(-z)^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-u)_n}{n!} z^n ,\quad |z| < 1.
$$

Thus we have
$$\int (1-z)^{u} z^{v} dz=
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-u)_{n}}{n!}\int z^{n+v}dz = z^{v+1}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-u)_{n}}{n! (n+v+1)}z^{n}.$$

Next, $\frac{1}{n+v+1}$ can be expressed as
$$\frac{1}{n+v+1}=\frac{\Gamma(n+v+1)}{\Gamma(n+v+2)} = \frac{\Gamma(v+1)(v+1)_n}{\Gamma(v+2)(v+2)_n} = \frac{(v+1)_n}{(v+1)(v+2)_n}.$$

Then
$$\int (1-z)^{u} z^{v} dz=
\frac{z^{v+1}}{v+1}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-u)_{n}(v+1)_n}{n!(v+2)_n}z^{n}=\frac{z^{v+1}}{v+1}\,_2F_1(-u,v+1;v+2;z).$$

Comment: Perhaps start with $$\binom{u}{n} = \frac{(-1)^n(-u)_n}{n!}$$and$$(1-z)^u = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{u}{v}(-z)^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-u)_n}{n!} z^n$$

Comment: @GeraldEdgar, please, go ahead with the modifications. Thanks!